# Cointegration of order 2

Tags: multivariate-analysis, cointegration, unit-root

Can we use the Johansen Test of Cointegration when the we have 7 variables that 6 of them are i(2) and one of them is i(0)?

Comment: What are your variables actually? What do they measure?

Comment: I am using six WGI variables and test their causality with the Economic growth. one of the six explanatory variables is i(0) and the rest are i(2).

Comment: I have no clue what WGI is, while economic growth is probably (relative) change in GDP and thus I(0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclude the I(0) variable from the cointegration analysis (there can be no cointegration among variables who are not integrated to begin with) and proceed with the remaining 6 variables as usual.

Comment: As the base model, I use the Toda-Yamamoto but before that I want to check the cointegration among the variables that explained before.

Comment: Great. My answer still applies.